# showing overlay window when the app is running in background or killed not working

Tags: flutter, firebase

I want to use the future void named `showOverlayWindow()` in onbackgroundmessage like in onmessage Flutter

```
void initState() {

    FirebaseMessaging.onMessage.listen(
      (RemoteMessage message) {
        showOverlayWindow();
        debugPrint("onMessage:");
        log("onMessage: $message");
        final snackBar =
            SnackBar(content: Text(message.notification?.title ?? ""));
        ScaffoldMessenger.of(context).showSnackBar(snackBar);
      },
    );
    FirebaseMessaging.onBackgroundMessage((message) => showOverlayWindow());
    super.initState();
    _initPlatformState();
    _requestPermissions();
    //_showOverlayWindow();

    SystemAlertWindow.registerOnClickListener(callBack);
  }
```

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.